# ODBC Command Errors on Execute with SQL0666 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odbc

I am running an ASP.NET 4.0 Application that uses an OdbcCommand. By default the Command Timeout is 30 seconds. When I run my web page my query errors with a "SQL0666 - SQL query exceeds specified time limit or storage limit." error. The Execute Reader line fails in less than 2 seconds on execution, far less than the Command Timeout. I added a line to set the CommandTimeout to 300 seconds and executed the code. The Execute Reader runs and the entire page loads in 15 seconds, again far less than the Command Timeout value. If I  run change the line I added to set the Command Timeout to 30 seconds, the code errors in under 2 seconds with the same error as above. The query itself is only about 15 lines long and runs in an IDE in a matter of seconds.

Original code that errors in less than two seconds

```
using (IDataReader reader = this._commandExecuter.ExecuteReader(cmdData))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Code that runs in 15 seconds:

```
cmdData.CommandTimeout = 300;
using (IDataReader reader = this._commandExecuter.ExecuteReader(cmdData))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Code that errors in less than 2 seconds:

```
 cmdData.CommandTimeout = 30;
using (IDataReader reader = this._commandExecuter.ExecuteReader(cmdData))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Have you found a solution other than setting the timeout to a value that works?

Comment: What does `_commandExecuter` do? Just return `cmdData.ExecuteReader()`? Why the abstraction?

Comment: We use abstraction to allow mocked calls against database for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue sometime, and we set the timeout to zero to fix:

```
cmdData.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Comment: This does work, but I am wondering why I am getting this error when the entire page loads in under the query timeout.